# Getting year value using

Tags: datetime, excel, vba

I want to get year value of a date that is stored in a cell. Foe example, there is date value 3/25/2012  stored in cell B35 and I am using `Year(Range("B35"))`. It gives me value of 1.6 as a result. i tried using date function to convert the value, but did not work. Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test `Year(Range("B35"))` with the date you gave, I get 2012. Since you haven't specified a sheet, VBA refers to B35 on the *ActiveSheet*. My guess is that B35 on one of your workbook's sheets contains the value 1.6.

To fix the issue, add this to your code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("YourSheetName")

Year(ws.Range("B35"))
```

Comment: Not referring to the sheet name was the problem as @ARich mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the cell's value - a range is an object, the value it hold is a property:

```
year(Sheets("SheetName").cells(35,2).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the datepart function? I think Year(arg) returns a string.

```
dim yr as date
yr = Sheets("yoursheetnamehere").Range("B35").Value
yr = datepart("yyyy", yr)
```

Can't hop on to test it right now but that should work with correct syntax.

Comment: Not referring to the sheet name was the problem as @ARich mentioned. Thanks